# immediate children of a list

Tags: javascript

A quick question.. what's the JAVASCRIPT statement to get the immediate children of a LIST? I tried:

```
document.getElementById(id).getElementsByTagName('li');
```

which gives me all of the child nodes.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

loop through:

`document.getElementById(id).children`

and get the ones that are li elements (I think they should all be according to spec)

---

I think `document.querySelectorAll('#id>li')` if it is supported should work as well. See:
http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/

Comment: Hmm, looks like children isn't part of a DOM standard, just part of gecko and perhaps other rendering engines... childNodes is probably the better answer even if you have to check each element of the list.

Comment: so is that document.getElementById(id).childNodes; that would get me only the immediate children?

Comment: yes, note that if you have firebug installed, you can see both of these lists in the watch window right on this site with a watch like `document.getElementsByTagName("ul")[0]`

Comment: The correct form for `querySelectorAll` that worked for me was `document.getElementById('id').querySelectorAll("li")`

Comment: That should be the same result, I am not sure which is faster and haven't tested but it looks like it gives the same results in a quick test in firefox and chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/9GgCE/, and according to mdn it `querySelectorAll` is available on both Document and Element classes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll

Answer (score 4):

[`Node.childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.childNodes) or [`Element.children`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.children)

```
var listItems = [];

var children = elem.childNodes;
for(var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    if(children[i].nodeName == "LI") {
        listItems.push(children[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `childNodes` contains all nodes and just elements.

Comment: thanks @Gumbo - I will clarify that point in the answer later. Shouldn't matter for small lists as we're testing by `nodeName`, but may be an inefficient for larger lists.

Comment: Better use `children[i].nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE` to make sure it’s really an element node.

Comment: `LI` shouldn't be returned as the nodeName for any other type of node. Since `nodeName` is defined on `Node`, it should be available as a property for all nodes, including text, and others.

Answer (score 2):

The same code faster & better.

```
var listItems = [];
var children = element.childNodes;
for(var i = 0, l=children.length; i<l; ++i) {
    var child = children[i];
    if(child.nodeType === 1 && child.tagName === "LI") {
        listItems.push(child);
    }
}
```