# How to select <li> inside <ul>

Tags: javascript, html

Assume I have html structure as

```
ul
  li //this one
    ul
      li
      li
      li
  li //this one
```

I don't want to get all `li`'s.
As I commented I just want to get first segment li's. How can I select them?

```
document.querySelectorAll("ul > li");
```

returns all `li`'s.

edit: actually this is just a snippet of the tree.
I can't modify the structure as adding class or id. I'm looking for an answer to get the list of first layer `li`s

Comment: add some class or id to your li, like <li class="first-block-li"> ... </li> and then use document.getElementByClass('first-block-li')

Comment: I can't modify the structure as adding class or id. Anything else?

Comment: What is `li` that you would be select? First, last or another?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [immediate children of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160119/immediate-children-of-a-list)

Comment: @Aotik — Not a duplicate. That is predicated on being able to identify the outer list in the first place.

Comment: To get the first `ul` you'd just run `document.querySelector('ul')`

Comment: If you can add the parent, you could use:  `document.querySelectorAll("div > ul:first-of-type > li");`  In this example, the parent is a `<div>`.  Source:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/22461943/4065876

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to select all the li items where the grandparent is not another list item.

```
:not(li) > * > li {}
```

This will only work if you don't have extra elements in the markup.

For example it would fail with:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
```

A slower, but more reliable, approach would be to get all the list items and then filter out ones which had list item ancestors.

```js
var lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
var lis_without_li_ancestors = [];
for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
  var element = lis[i];
  if (!has_li_ancestor(element)) {
    lis_without_li_ancestors.push(element);
  }
}

console.log(lis_without_li_ancestors);

function has_li_ancestor(element) {
  var parent = element.parentNode;
  if (parent.tagName.toLowerCase() === "body") {
    return false;
  } else if (parent.tagName.toLowerCase() === "li") {
    return true;
  } else {
    return has_li_ancestor(parent);
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>...
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: is this the syntax for it document.querySelectorAll(":not(li) > * > li {}"); ?

Comment: @Olof — `{}` isn't part of the selector.

Comment: Ok, so this then? document.querySelectorAll(":not(li) > * > li");

Comment: Tell me if I'm wrong, but your solution is the same as:
`document.querySelector("ul").children`

Comment: @nidstang — You're wrong. Neither of my solutions are the same as that.

Comment: @Quentin, i just try both solutions (@nidstang) and actually achieve the same results, but nidstang one is far shorter. can you explain why yours is better? I dont understand.

Answer (score 5):

In jQuery you can use this selector `ul > li:not('ul > li > ul > li')`:

```js
$("ul > li:not('ul > li > ul > li')").css("background", "green");
```

```css
ul > li {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    First
    <ul>
      <li>
        Second
        <ul>
          <li>Third</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Second</li>
      <li>Second</li>
      <li>Second</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>First</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this it should do the trick :

```
$("ul > li").not("ul li ul li");
```

Also this should work in your case :

```
$("ul").first().children("li");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `id` to that specific `li`:

```
<li id="someID"></li>
```

then select it using:

```
var chosenOne = document.getElementById("someID");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could traverse the first ul's children and look for li's like the following.

```
function firstLis() {
  var firstUl = document.querySelector('ul');
  var list = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < firstUl.children.length; i++) {
    var element = firstUl.children[i];
    if(element.tagName === 'LI')
      list.push(element);
  }
  return list;
}
```

Comment: Why would `document.querySelector('ul')` not return the nested `ul`s?

Comment: @Arg0n — It would. That's why you need the code that appears after that line.

Comment: [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns the first element found.

Comment: @FrederikHansen I see, but then it would not work for multiple lists in the root. `<ul><li></li></ul> <ul><li></li></ul>`.

Comment: @Arg0n You're right, it wouldn't. If you wanted to extend this to work for all ul's in a given parent element you could do something like `document.querySelectorAll('body > ul')` and then run the function on all of those.

Answer (score -1):

use `:scope`

```js
console.log(source.querySelectorAll("ul:scope > li"));
```

```html
<ul id="source">
  <li>
    this
    <ul>
      <li>not this</li>
      <li>not this</li>
      <li>not this</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
  this
  </li>
</ul>
```

Snapshot from Chrome console:

[image]

Comment: Which browser did you use? Tested with Chrome / Firefox it works.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback (from deleted comment). I cannot test it with IE for now, maybe it's an not-so-compatible answer but it works with Chrome / Firefox. hope it helps someone in the future.

Comment: I don't agree with the downvote, but change your answer as to an alternative for modern browsers or (specific browsers) :) good answer.

Answer (score -2):

You can get the father's direct children. In this case, the "lis":

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("ul").children)
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this wouldn't work 

actually it select the inner ul

Comment: you right, but you can select the "lis" from those "uls". I don't know but I think it's easier than other answers.

Comment: we need only the "lis" of the first layer 

in your case the inner "ul" wouldn't give us the right "lis"

Comment: hummm ok. it could be something like this: `document.querySelector("ul").children` ?
Maybe I am not understanding you.